# Playwright "No test is available"

Tags: testing, .net-core, playwright

I have followed the Playwright installation instructions for .net and NUnit, and added the example test from https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/intro#add-example-tests but when I run "dotnet test" I get:

```
Starting test execution, please wait... 
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern. 
No test is available in <my path>. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and
platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
```

That message suggests it located my test file, but then no test was available/discovererable?

What am I missing (that's not mentioned in the installation notes)?

Comment: Is it runnable from the IDE?

Comment: That's an interesting point. MS don't seem to make any mention of running Playwright tests from Visual Studio, only from VS Code. I thought Visual Studio was their flagship IDE.

Comment: Yes I find that gap quite a large one. If you kick it off as one would a unit test, directly in your IDE via Test Runner, you will see if the issue is the test code or some configuration issue.